# Add a condition to this loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to add another condition to what I have here already in Python 3.  What I need is it to find out if the number entered is more than >=0 and display an error if it is not and ask the question again until a value >=0 is entered.

```
for i in range (number):
        days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day in days:
            while True:
                try:
                    case = int(input("Please enter number of cases for {} ".format(day)))
                    weeks.append(case)
                    break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please Enter a Number")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the case is positive or equal to 0, add a condition to the case.
i.e. the code would look like:

```
for i in range(number): 
        days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
        for day in days:
            while True:
                try:
                    case = int(input("Please enter number of cases for {} ".format(day)))
                    if case >= 0: 
                         weeks.append(case)
                         break
                except ValueError:
                    print("Please Enter a Number")
```

In this way, if case is less than 0, it will not break .

Comment: Thanks for that.  That is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just do what you are saying:

```
if case < 0:
  print("Please Enter a Number >= 0")
  continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
case = input()
while True:
    if int(case) >= 0:
        break
    else:
        case = input()
```

Just FYI this will cause an error with floats or strings